# couldn't use values from server in html input element

Tags: php, html

```php
<?php
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'ohe';    

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE `rollno` LIKE '15csr178'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result1)
    {
        $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

        $rollno=$result['rollno'];
        $name=$result['name'];
        $gender=$result['gender'];
        $course=$result['course'];

        $branch=$result['branch'];
        $courseduration=$result['courseduration'];
        $hostel=$result['hostel'];
        $roomno=$result['roomno'];
        $gmail=$result['gmail'];
        $summa="hello";
        echo $summa;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'enter valid';
    }

    //mysqli_close($conn);

    echo $summa;  

    echo"<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    NAME : <input type='text' id='rollno' value=".<?php echo htmlspecialchars($summa); ?> ."/>

    </body>

    </html>";    

    echo $summa;    
?>
```

I've a form which I need to autofill the input elements with the data from server.

I'm able to fetch data from server, I've checked with echo for each field but when I use it to populate the input elements simply the whole php tag is getting displayed instead of that value ...

What could be the mistake in the code above?

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole php tag is getting displayed instead of that value" ?

Comment: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($summa); ?>  i'm getting this inside the input element

Comment: take out the periods

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' this results when the periods are removed

Comment: you. need to close your php tags before opening new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<?php echo` from your script. You're already in PHP and concatenating the variables. You do not need to use the opening php tags in order to echo the variable when concatenating.

Comment: very Thank you it's working